# Editor in not showing correct line number when enter key pressed continuously in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, editor, keyevent

I'm trying to build the editor using JavaScript. I want to show line count like 1,2,3 on line change on pressing enter. I did count line change when pressed enter But problem arises I continuously pres enter then sequence of line change like 1,2, 12 as keyup event not work at that time becoz of continuous pressing.

I'm using textarea in html

```
    <div class="editor-flex">
        <div id="editor-numbering">
            <div>1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-block">
            <textarea name="text" id="editor"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="output">
            Preview
        </div>
    </div>
```

main.js file here **div is create to store new line**

```
let editor =  document.getElementById("editor")
let editorNumbering = document.querySelector('#editor-numbering')
let len =1;

editor.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    // console.log(editor.value)
    let lenNew =  editor.value.split('\n').length //count line change
    console.log(len)
    if(len!=lenNew)
    {    
        let  div = document.createElement('div')
        div.textContent = len+1
        console.log(div)
        editorNumbering.append(div)
    }
    len = lenNew
    console.log(len)

})
```

The expected result is the continuous line count like in any kind of other editor that show result 1,2,3, to when line changes pressing enter key continuously or single

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by *continuously pres enter*? Maybe, you can use `keydown` event instead of `keyup`:

```js
let editor =  document.getElementById("editor")
let editorNumbering = document.querySelector('#editor-numbering')
let len =1;

editor.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    // console.log(editor.value)
    let lenNew =  editor.value.split('\n').length //count line change
    //console.log(len)
    if(len!=lenNew)
    {    
        let  div = document.createElement('div')
        div.textContent = len+1
        //console.log(div)
        editorNumbering.append(div)
    }
    len = lenNew
    //console.log(len)

})
```

```html
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<div id="editor-numbering"></div>
```